# HDD no longer able to mount after editing /etc/fstab

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have an SSD which holds / and my home directory, but I also have a 1TB HDD with most of my music on. I tried to edit /etc/fstab to automatically mount the HDD to save me time. I am running Kubuntu.

I opened KDE Partition Manager to check the type of the filesystem and it read ext3

The line I added read:

```
/dev/sda /media/HDD ext3 defaults 0 2
```

On rebooting, an error appeared under 'Kubuntu' on the boot screen saying that the filesystem couldn't mount so I hit S to skip attempting to mount.

Running `sudo blkid` shows:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="HDD" UUID="00000000-dba3-409e-a185-345c60459125" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="44cdc69c-0746-4a99-9c48-ccf7fca69768" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="478bf04c-8bf6-46c4-86e8-e844380cf8e7" TYPE="swap"
```

I can remember when I created the partition originally, I didn't set it to ext2 (even though this was ~2 years ago)

I attempted a couple more times with different options (changing defaults to other commands rw,async,auto...). The HDD will no longer mount. When opening in dolphin, the message reads:

> An error occurred while accessing 'Home', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/myname/HDD: Command-line `mount -t "ext2" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda1" "/media/myname/HDD"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

KDE Partition Manager says the type is unknown. Clicking 'properties' shows it as unformatted

`fdisk -l` gives the following:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000819ae

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63  1953520064   976760001   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes     
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001a3c6                                    

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048   233330687   116664320   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2       233332734   250068991     8368129    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       233332736   250068991     8368128   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Attempting to mount gives the error

```
~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda /media/HDD
[sudo] password for myname: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

`dmesg | tail` says:

```
[ 5632.049404] EXT2-fs (sda): error: ext2_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 880 not in group (block 0)!
[ 5632.049411] EXT2-fs (sda): group descriptors corrupted
[ 5669.867629] EXT2-fs (sda): error: ext2_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 880 not in group (block 0)!
[ 5669.867632] EXT2-fs (sda): group descriptors corrupted
[ 6894.395961] EXT2-fs (sda1): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sda1.
[ 7040.625599] EXT3-fs (sda1): error: fragsize 1024 != blocksize 4096 (unsupported)
[ 7045.462213] EXT2-fs (sda1): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sda1.
[ 7048.975278] EXT4-fs (sda1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 7421.551590] EXT2-fs (sda1): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sda1.
[ 7451.874417] EXT2-fs (sda1): error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sda1.
```

strace:

```
$ strace -s 2000 -o mount.log blkid

/dev/sda1: LABEL="HDD" UUID="00000000-dba3-409e-a185-345c60459125" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="44cdc69c-0746-4a99-9c48-ccf7fca69768" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="478bf04c-8bf6-46c4-86e8-e844380cf8e7" TYPE="swap"
```

/proc/filesystems:

```
$ cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cpuset
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   anon_inodefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext4
nodev   ramfs
nodev   hugetlbfs
        vfat
nodev   ecryptfs
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
nodev   binfmt_misc
        ext2
        udf
```

Comment: Have you tried to mount it with the `mount` command. Eg `sudo mount /dev/sda some_dir`. If it succeeds, run `mount` again to see the filesystem type. If you still have problems, post the output here.

Comment: `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so`

Comment: Wait, there is a partition on it, sorry missed that - `sudo mount /dev/sda1 some_dir`

Comment: Your description is inconsistent. You mention three data volumes (`/`, `/home` and your music) but there are only two: `sda1` and `sdb1`.

Comment: @Huake, music is on sda1.

Comment: You prob just need to have `/dev/sda1` in your `fstab`.

Comment: `EXT3-fs (sda1): error: fragsize 1024 != blocksize 4096 (unsupported)`. Looks like its `ext3` after all. Hopefully a `fsck` will solve things, `sudo fsck.ext3 /dev/sda1`.

Comment: @Hugo, wait, just saw your `strace` comment, could you post the relevant part of that output too please.

Comment: @Graeme Updated now

Comment: @slm's `file` method looks like a good way to go. I is obviously looking at more than just the magic number (which could be misleading). `sudo file -s /dev/sda1`

Comment: @Graeme `/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=00000000-dba3-409e-a185-345c60459125, volume name "HDD"` I'm not sure what the `dmesg` results mean. Is it as bad as it looks? Is it fixable?

Comment: It is worrying that `dmesg` says `error: can't find an ext2 filesystem on dev sda1.` The fact it didn't say anything like that for `ext3` is what made me think it was that. This is confusing. Try `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` | grep Filesystem`. I think there is obviously some a filesystem error, but hopefully this can be repaired. We just need to know which filesystem first! (that said you could always try each `fsck.extX` command, I don't *think* it would hurt)

Comment: @Graeme Using the info from the answers here, I did some more research and found an article recommending `fsck` with a backup superblock. Sadly this article had a typo that said `mke2fs /dev/sda1` instead of `mke2fs -n /dev/sda1`. /headdesk

Comment: Ouch. Guess we'll never know the type now. Did you have a lot of stuff on it? There are various methods to still recover data, especially media files.

Comment: `PhotoRec` - http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec

Comment: @Graeme There was quite a lot of data on it. It was stuff backed-up from my (broken) laptop, I just hadn't had time to backup my backup! I have hard copies of most of my music so it's not a total loss and almost everything else I can re-download from various online services. I'll look into PhotoRec to get the rest back, thanks!

Comment: @Graeme PhotoRec didn't show anything from the drive. I'll give it a shot on the other drive (which broke and the more recently broken drive was a backup for) but I just found that I also had all of the important data (that I'd forgotten was on there) backed-up again! Phew!

Comment: That was lucky!

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to determine a drives filesystem type. Here's a list of the tools I'm familiar with.

#### 1. blkid

Works whether device is mounted or not.

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="XXXX" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

#### 2. mount

This is only useful once the block device has been mounted.

```
$ sudo mount | grep /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```

#### 3. lsblk

Shows drive topologies, but not the filesystem types on the devices.

```
$ sudo lsblk -a
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                      8:2    0 465.3G  0 part
```

#### tune2fs

```
$ tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep magic
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
```

Shows the magic number associated with the device, you can look these up on this site, [Linux Magic Numbers](http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html). It's also in a file, often here, `/usr/share/magic`. You can locate it using `locate /magic`.

#### dumpe2fs

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep magic
dumpe2fs 1.42.7 (21-Jan-2013)
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
```

Same things apply as in `tune2fs`.

#### /dev/mounts

This is the "file" maintained by the kernel that's used to display devices that have been mounted. **NOTE:** many of the tools on this list are typically using the contents of this file.

```
$ sudo cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

#### file

You can also use the `file` command to display info about unmounted filesystems.

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=XXXX (needs journal recovery) (extents) (huge files)
```

An alternative syntax (as root):

```
$ file - </dev/sda1
/dev/stdin: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=XXXX (needs journal recovery) (extents) (huge files)
```

#### Your mounting issue

I'd suspect that the filesystem you're attempting to mount is not what you think it is. Either the entire device was formatted with a filesystem (`/dev/sda`), in which case you'd be mounting the entire drive. You can test this hypothesis like this:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt
```

Of if you need to explicitly tell what filesystem to use:

```
$ sudo mount -o ext2 /dev/sda /mnt
```

**NOTE:** This is generally not the case that an entire filesystem is laid down on the entire device, `/dev/sda`, rather they're partitioned into `/dev/sda1`, etc.

Or perhaps the drive has been partitioned. In this case you'd see these partitions with the above command `lsblk`, where they'd show up as `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, etc. If that's the case for you then you'll need to mount the partition instead like so:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Again pay special attention to the formatting used on the filesystem of the device, you'll occasionally have to specify it literally to `mount`.

Since your output from `fdisk` shows that you have `/dev/sda1` I'd be inclined to think that you have your filesystem on the 1st partition.

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63  1953520064   976760001   83  Linux
```

So mounting it like this should do the trick:

```
$ sudo mount -o ext2 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

#### /etc/fstab

If the above mounting commands work then you can add this to your `/etc/fstab` file.

```
/dev/sda1 /media/HDD ext2 defaults 0 2
```

Comment: Some useful info here, I will definitely be remembering the `file` one for future use.

Answer (score 6):

Your mount entry

```
/dev/sda /media/HDD ext3 defaults 0 2
```

contains several errors:

1. `sda` must be `sda1` (or `sdb1`)
2. `ext3` must be `ext2` or `ext4` (depending on (1))

Usually you

1. should mount a volume successfully on the command line before entering it in `fstab`
2. use your distro's tool for editing `fstab`

Comment: From Q: 'I opened KDE Partition Manager to check the type of the filesystem and it read ext3'.

Comment: ext3 is prob right, and sda is the 1 TB HDD, so he just needs sda1 by the looks of things.

Comment: @Graeme The question contains the output of `blkid` and that is `ext2` and `ext4`.

Comment: Must be getting old, need to get myself some reading glasses...

Comment: @Graeme You did read right. I didn't notice the KDE info. But what is probably more reliable? And why should one use `ext2` on such a huge volume?

Comment: running `mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /media/HDD` gives the same error (wrong fs type). Same for ext2 and ext4

Comment: @Hugo, don't include the `-t` option and run with no args after. I have no idea where the other programs get the filesystem from, but mount is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: @HugoBuff Try `mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/HDD`

Comment: @HaukeLaging same fs error again. @Graeme What info do you want from `mount`? The only dev mounted is sdb1 (the SSD) as type ext4

Comment: @Hugo If you mount successfully, mount will tell you the file system type. It is the definitive way, if you give `-t auto` or no type, it just tries the most likely options in turn until it mounts successfully. Its worrying that you still have an error. Does `/media/HDD` definitely exist?

Comment: @Hugo You could also post the output of `dmesg | tail`

Comment: @Graeme - `strace -s 2000 -o mount.log blkid` will show you this.

Comment: @Hugo, what slm says.

Comment: @Graeme Yeah. `/media/HDD` exists. tbh I don't know what's happened and how it's managed to go so wrong just from trying to mount!

Comment: @Graeme `strace` shows sda1 as type ext2. I have edited the post with `dmesg | tail` which doesn't look promising

Comment: Have you used this drive with other OSs? Can it be that this is an NTFS, HFS volume or something else which Linux does not support directly?

Comment: @Hugo, you can see the list of filesystems tried by mount in `/etc/filesystems` or if that doesn't exist `/proc/filesystems`

Comment: @Graeme added to main Q