# mounting mmcblk0p1 failed with Invalid argument

Tags: mount

When I am running linux from sd card and try to mount sd card -no problem, works fine. But when I am running linux from flash memory I am unable to mount my SD card:

```
# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/ 
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 on /mnt/ failed: Invalid argument
```

What could be the basic reason for this error ?

**Additional Info**

```
root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/# mount -t /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
mount: can't find /mnt in /etc/fstab 

root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/var/volatile/log# ls
wtmp

root@Xilinx-ZC702-14_7:/var/volatile/log# dmesg
dmesg: klogctl: Function not implemented
```

Comment: Please try the complete command (`-t ...`) so that the `fstab` entry is not used.

Comment: Does anything useful get written into `/var/log/messages`? How about `dmesg | tail`?

Comment: @Flup i updated my question above

Comment: `mount -t /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt` isn't a complete command. If you know the filesytem type, you should specify it after the -t argument (e.g. `mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt`) or omit -t completely.

Comment: omitting did not work as you can see above

Comment: The question is very confusing. An SD card **is** flash memory. "running linux from sd card" ... "running linux from flash memory".

Comment: What H.L. meant in the first place (`-t ...`), and J.H is pointing out, is that `-t` **requires a parameter**, namely the filesystem type (`vfat`, `ext3`, etc.).  *Read the man pages*.

Comment: Did you manage to mount the device here? If not, please update with more information.

Comment: The kernel can probably mount the filesystem, but it wrongly guess its type. How did you partition and format the flash drive?

Comment: Under busybox, even with the full option mounting an SD card fails when trying to mount ext4.

Answer (score 13):

As [commented by goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118090/mounting-mmcblk0p1-failed-with-invalid-argument#comment192054_118090), `mount -t` expects the filesystem type to come after `-t`, so it won't work. Otherwise it sounds like you just need to specify the filesystem type. If you don't know the filesystem type, then there are a list of methods to find out in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117691/48083). If the `file` command is available, this is probably the best method. As root you would do:

```
file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Note also that if the filesystem type is not in listed in `/proc/filesystems`, then the driver is not compiled into the kernel and so must be available as an external module. Once you have the correct type, you can try:

```
mount -t correct_type /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
```

As a final thought, also make sure the `/mnt` directory exists! If not create it with `mkdir /mnt`.

Comment: mounts requires sudo?

Comment: @Ferroao, yes mounting requires root privileges.

Comment: if i need to modify , create files in that sd will I need sudo?

Comment: @Ferroao, that depends on the filesystem you are trying to mount. For Linux filesystems permissions/owner/group on each file/directory determine who can read/write.

Answer (score 4):

Basic reasons: (updated)

1) Your system does not (properly?) initialize or does not recognize the SD when booting from flash. Is there the `/dev/mmcblk0` device after you boot from flash? What does `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` say?

2) There is no file system on /dev/mmcblk0p1, you need to create a file system first (`mkfs ...`). Check with `file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1`

3) The file system on /dev/mmcblk0p1 is corrupted, you need to check / repair it, try `fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1`, or create a new one

4) Your kernel (when booting from flash) does not have the needed file system driver, check `cat /proc/filesystems` and `ls "/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/"` and see if that list contains the needed file system type. Typically, older kernels don't support ext4, while your OS might already have tools to create an ext4 file system.

5) Hardware defect - could be the SD card, the controller, wiring ... but if it works when booting from the SD card then this is most probably not the case.

Comment: Note that the filesystems listed in `/proc/filesystems` are only the ones which are compiled into the kernel. For example my `/proc/filesystems` doesn't contain `vfat`, but I can still mount a `vfat` system since it is available as a module.

Comment: Looks good, although the OP may just have to specify the type. The `util-linux` mount tries to identify the filesystem via `blkid` then attempts everything in `/etc/filesystems` or `/proc/filesystem`. I think this is the `busybox` mount, so it probably does less. Either would likely miss a specialist flash filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

First check the file systems supported in the kernel.

```
[kevin@hexcore ~]
$ cat /proc/filesystems 
....
    ext3
    ext2
    ext4
....
```

I assume that you are trying to mount the same SD card from which you are running the Linux. If so, I assume, quite reasonably, that it has native file system support in Linux. To make sure you have loaded the SD card driver, you can try,

```
$ sudo modprobe sdhci
$ dmesg | tail -n 10
sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
```

Now, try read access to partitions:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk of=/dev/null bs=4k count=0  # note: count = 0
```

Alternatively:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk
```

`fdisk` will tell you the partition types as well.

This assures you that the SD card driver can access the block device.
Now you can run `parted` to print the file systems:

```
$ sudo parted /dev/mmcblk
(parted) p
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  8000MB  7999MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      8000MB  500GB   492GB   primary  ext4
```

Once you know the FS, mount it with

```
$ sudo mount -t <FS> /dev/mmcblkpX </target/dir>
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? parted can analyze the signature as well as far as I can remember.  fdisk just dumps the partition type.

Comment: Ok, your right, `parted` does try to determine the filesystem type. Comment removed.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to remember this is the error you get when the type of partition you're trying to mount isn't supported.

Comment: If you know what the partition type is, check the appropriate fsck function is in /sbin and that the appropriate modules are in the kernel (/proc/modules)

Comment: i dont know the partition type. is there any command to find the partition type? But I have see /proc/modules--its empty

Comment: If you have root this will be a lot easier, but if, as I think you are, you're doing this on Android, you're looking for *`blkid`,* if not, and it's a more conventional Linux environment, *`lsblk`* is probably preferable.

Comment: I will check lsblk tomorrow.But why is /proc/modules empty.

Comment: How can you know that and still be a whole day away from typing 5 letters at your prompt?

Comment: if you can mount it on a different system, you can cat /proc/mounts or /etc/mtab to see what was mounted, it'll tell you in there what type of partition it was

Comment: if /proc/modules is empty, then you don't have any modules attached and are reliant entirely on what's been compiled into your kernel

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to use (parted command) due to partition size:

```
# /sbin/parted /dev/mmcblk0p1
(parted) mklabel gpt
this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? yes
....
(parted) quit
```

To make sure that the partition is properly created use `/sbin/parted /dev/mmcblk0p1 print”`

Then you have to format the created partition

```
/sbin/mkfs -t correct_type /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Comment: Using `parted` on `/dev/mmcblk0p1` will create a partition table on a partition of a device which has already been partitioned. Also, following these instructions will **erase all data on the device**.